# Elegant way to obtain the smallest subset of binary matrix rows where each column sums to at least 1

Tags: matrices, binary, discrete-optimization

**Context:** 
I have $m$ groups of a random number of $n$ types. Each type can occur only once for each group. I hope to reduce the groups to the smallest set such that each type occurs at least once.

**Problem:**
Suppose I have an $n * m$ binary matrix which represents the groups of each type.

$$
    \begin{matrix}
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    \end{matrix}
$$

**Question:** Is there an elegant way to determine the smallest subset of rows such that each column sums to at least $1$.

In this example rows 1, 3 and 4 fulfill this.

$$
    \begin{matrix}
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    \end{matrix}
$$

I am a biological scientist, so it may be obvious that this is not possible. My Google and Stack Exchange searches did not reveal a method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a *set covering problem*, which you can solve via integer linear programming as follows.  Let $a_{i,j}$ be the $(i,j)$ entry of your matrix.  Let binary decision variable $x_i$ indicate whether you select row $i$.  The problem is to minimize $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$ subject to linear constraints:
$$\sum_{i=1}^n a_{i,j} x_i \ge 1$$
for each $j\in\{1,\dots,m\}$.

Comment: In addition, a practical solution to set cover problem is [greedy algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem#Greedy_algorithm)

Comment: Thanks so much, I just didn't have the vocabulary to ask my question.